# Merge two array of Objects based on different keys into one in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two Arrays of Objects Arr1 and Arr2. I want to merge these two based on their 'id'. If Arr1 does not have any object with same id as that of Arr2 it should push that object node into Arr1. How can I achieve it?

```
Arr1 =
[
  {
    'id'    : 101,
    'name'  : "ABC"
  },
  {
    'id'    : 202,
    'name'  : "DEF"
  }
];

Arr2 =
[
  {
    'id'    : 303,
    'name'  : "PQR"
  },
  {
    'id'    : 404,
    'name'  : "XYZ"
  },
  {
    'id'    : 202,
    'name'  : "DEF"
  }
];

Arr1 =
[
  {
    'id'    : 101,
    'name'  : "ABC"
  },
  {
    'id'    : 202,
    'name'  : "DEF"
  },
  {
    'id'    : 303,
    'name'  : "PQR"
  },
  {
    'id'    : 404,
    'name'  : "XYZ"
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the `Arr2` using `forEach` & inside call back use findIndex to check if the current element under iteration is present in `Arr1` or not. `findIndex` will return `index` if the element is present in array or `-1` if not present. If findIndex is `-1` then push that item from second array to Arr1

```js
let Arr1 = [{
    'id': 101,
    'name': "ABC"
  },
  {
    'id': 202,
    'name': "DEF"
  }
];

const Arr2 = [{
    'id': 303,
    'name': "PQR"
  },
  {
    'id': 404,
    'name': "XYZ"
  },
  {
    'id': 202,
    'name': "DEF"
  }
];



Arr2.forEach((item) => {
  const isPresentInArry1 = Arr1.findIndex(elem => elem.id === item.id);
  if (isPresentInArry1 === -1) {
    Arr1.push(item)
  }
});

console.log(Arr1)
```